# Save model tries to create new object

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following two Django models:

```
class A:
    uuid = CharField(primary_key=True)
    code = CharField(unique=True)

class B:
    uuid = CharField(primary_key=True)
    a = ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs')

    def save(**kwargs):
        self.a.save(**kwargs)
        super(B, self).save(**kwargs)
```

If I want to use them in a test case and write this function:

```
def setUp():
    a = A.objects.create(uuid='a')
    b = B.objects.create(uuid='b', a=a)
```

I get the following error:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: app_name_a.code
```

It looks like that in the save method of B, it tries to create another A with the same values instead of updating the existing instance. Why would this be so? I am using Python 3.5 and Django 1.8.14.

By the way: the reason I want to save the parent is that I have functionality in the save method that is updating an `updated_at` timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `kwargs` you passed into `A.save()`:

```
self.a.save(**kwargs)
```

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save), you'll see `force_insert` is sent `True` *(because `A` is being created at the moment)* when you try to save `B` so Django won't check if `self.a` has already been created because you are passing `force_insert` as `True` to `self.a.save()` as well.

To fix this, you should not pass `**kwargs` in order to let Django make the decision on creating or updating `self.a`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.a.save()
    super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It seems in the documentation that you refer to that the default is `force_insert=False`, but indeed, when I print `kwargs`, I see that is is indeed set and set to True!

Comment: @physicalattraction it'll be sent `True` because Django sets that value based on `self.pk` being `None` or not.